# Qt OpenGL error '_imp_gl...'

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

Trying to learn how to use QGLWidget, but already so much time wasted handling these errors. I dont even understand them. I googled, but nothing. Please, any suggestions?

Code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77c57fde631c77810775

```
In function `ZN6Widget12initializeGLEv':
 undefined reference to `_imp__glEnable@4'
 undefined reference to `_imp__glShadeModel@4'
 and more...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking against any GL library.

**Since Qt 5.5, on Windows, by default, Qt does not link against libGL**, but has a runtime mechanism for deciding to load either libGL or ANGLE (depending on your OS capabilities). This means you can't just use `glFoo` -- you will get linking errors.

---

Solution: go through function resolvers, for instance `QOpenGLFunctions`:

```
QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
f->glEnable(GL_FOOBAR);
f->glDrawArrays(...);
```

Note that on Windows you need function resolvers anyhow to use any OpenGL function introduced after 1.1.

Also, if you're using ES2-only or Desktop GL-only functions, you should force Qt to load the right GL implementation:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // *before* creating it
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

[**More info here.**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers)

<sub>(More radical solution: recompile Qt passing `-opengl desktop` or `-opengl es2` to configure).</sub>

Comment: but, actually, it turned out, that there are no fucnctions like glShadeModel, glMatrixMode and more. How can it be so? Am I using old tutorial?

Comment: Those *are* indeed from GL1. And you're not supposed to use them any more. Go through `QOpenGLFunctions_1_1` if you really need that.